# Windows Phone 8 Developer Registration issue in Nokia Lumia 920 as Sign in Page is blank

Tags: windows-phone-8

As per the registration process mentioned in below site for Windows Phone 8

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx

I have ensured below things :-

a. Unlocked the phone screen.

b. On my phone, I ensured that the date and time are correct.

c. Connected my phone to computer by using the USB cable.

d. Under Windows Phone SDK 8.0, I clicked Windows Phone Developer Registration.

e. But after clicking Register button, it gives blank Sign in Page

Please tell us the solution.

P.S. 1. The phone is not having sim card and hence not connected to internet. 
        However it is connected to the PC which is internet enabled.

```
 2. We had installed WP8 10322 Emulators.exe but that too didn't solve the problem
```

Comment: Have you run through the troubleshooting section on the link you provided and can you answer yes to all of the points? Also, please note that Stack Overflow is a question/answer site for specific development questions, troubleshooting and support requests aren't really suited. You might want to try the [Windows Phone Dev Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/wptools/threads).

Comment: Thanks. It was internet proxy issue. It was blocking Microsoft locking log in site.

It worked with different proxy

Answer (score 0):

Turn OFF the Time setting called Set Automatically and try again